# Is there a Visual Studio batch editor extension?

Tags: visual-studio, batch

I am working on a large Visual Studio project where the the build script is a `.cmd` file.
When opened using the Visual Studio's editor the file is recognized just like a normal text file - parenthesis are not recognized, no variable name completion or renaming options.
It makes editing more difficult and time consuming because you can only encounter a syntax bug while actually running the batch file..

I saw that for VS Code there is an add-on with all these abilities [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rechinformatica.rech-editor-batch).

I also checked out this [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/655/editor-for-writing-shell-scripts-with-autocompletion-and-syntax-highlighting) but it did not solve my question.

Is there any similar extension for Visual Studio?

I use Visual Studio Professional 2015 (Update 3) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

After long research I found an extension that does the trick!

`TextHighlighterExtension2015` for Visual Studio 2015.

[Installation link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FredericTorres.TextHighlighterExtension2015), or available at the store.

There is a comment that you have to run VS15 as admin when you install it if you do it from the online store.